# Node continues execution even though a response has been sent

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have something along the lines of the below code:

```
const checkForSpaces = text => !/\s/g.test(text)

const verifyLink = async (res) => {
    return res.status(400).end()
}

router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
    const { email, password, verifyToken } = req.body

    if (verifyingAdmin) {
        await verifyLink(res, verifyToken)
    }

    // Code below this line should not be reached
    try {
        if (!checkForSpaces(email)) {
          return res.status(400).json({ msg: "Email cannot have spaces" })
        }
    . . . .
```

There is a use case where `email` and `password` are `null` and in that use case, in `verifyLink`, I send a response back to the frontend, however I run into an error, `Cannot read property 'trim' of null` for the obvious reason that those aforementioned fields are `null`. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The execution goes on because you don't return from the function. Just add a `return` after `await verifyLink(res, verifyToken)`. The `return` in `verifyLink` will only end the execution of the `verifyLink` function, not of the parent function.